# SQL reduce duplicates in union clause

Tags: sql, oracle

let's say for example I have the following query:

```
SELECT City, Country FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany'
UNION
SELECT City, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany'
ORDER BY City;
```

As you can see the `WHERE Country='Germany'` is repeated in both the targets of the union - is there any way to reduce this to a query without repetitions? I don't like my queries being too long.

I'm currently working on Oracle.

Comment: Use subquery-factoring, i.e. `WITH` clause to avoid repeated subqueries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not include the `WHERE` only once like

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT City, Country FROM Customers
UNION ALL
SELECT City, Country FROM Suppliers
ORDER BY City
) tab 
WHERE Country='Germany'
```

(OR) do a `JOIN` like

```
SELECT c.City as CustomerCity, c.Country as customerCountry, 
s.City as suppliercity, s.Country as suppliercountry
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Suppliers s ON c.Country = s.Country
AND c.Country='Germany'
ORDER BY c.City;
```

Comment: Is there a special reason for the `union all`? The example I put up just uses a `union`.

Comment: @dk123: UNION ALL will not filter out duplicates, UNION does, and costs you an extra sort/group operation.

Comment: `[INNER] JOIN` version may return different resultset

Comment: @dk123, with `union all` all rows will be combined including the dups.

Comment: @a1ex07, why so? Well, the display result will not look same since union and join are different things but data returned should be same.

Comment: @Rahul: say if `Customers` or `Suppliers` (but not both) has 0 records for Germany, resultset is gonna be empty. `UNION` version will return non-empty resultset

Comment: @a1ex07, Ahh!!! Nice point friend, I completely missed that. Thank You. Edited my answer to include a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: @Rahul : It seems you're still missing something in your `LEFT JOIN` version. I guess `FROM (SELECT 'Germany' as country FROM dual)a LEFT JOIN Suppliers ON (Suppliers.country = a.country ) LEFT JOIN Customers ON (Customers.country = a.country) .... ` would give desired result. Anyway, it doesn't matter much, you have your question accepted already :)

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct city, country
from
(
   SELECT City, Country FROM Customers
   WHERE Country='Germany'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT City, Country FROM Suppliers
   WHERE Country='Germany'
) x
order by city
```

You can't really get around the need for a `UNION` if you really want both sets of rows: I've added a `UNION ALL` inside the main SQL and a `DISTINCT` outside to remove duplicates but with no extra sort operations (assuming you want to do that).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT City, Country FROM Customers
    UNION
    SELECT City, Country FROM Suppliers
) t
WHERE t.Country='Germany'
ORDER BY t.City;
```

Answer (score 2):

The code that you already have is pretty compact and clear while not sacrificing performance.

The suggestions to use a subquery can eliminate the duplicate WHERE statements, but will require more i/o activity than the simple union you originally provided. 
When there is a union inside the sub query and then a WHERE outside of it this is asking the SQL engine to build a temporary table that is all rows in the customer table added to all the rows in the supplier table and then query that resulting table throwing out the rows which are not country = Germany. If your tables only have a couple hundred rows and you are running the query locally, it will likely not show much performance difference, but if you have thousands of rows or tables are on different servers across the network, performance could be orders of magnitude slower.

If performance is a consideration, you could make the query a bit simpler and more maintainable by using a variable for the country like so:

```
VAR country varchar2(64);
EXEC :country := 'Germany';

SELECT City, Country FROM Customers
WHERE Country=' :country
UNION
SELECT City, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country= :country
ORDER BY City;
```

This clearly does not make for shorter code, but it is somewhat cleaner and would be easier to modify and only retrieves the rows that you are interested in which will give better performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a common table expression (CTE):

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT City, Country FROM Customers
    UNION
    SELECT City, Country FROM Suppliers)
SELECT  City, Country  
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.Country='Germany'
ORDER BY CTE.City;
```

I find it easier to read than nested sub-queries.

Comment: Much better. As a single subquery, a CTE would perform efficiently than repeated sub-queries.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Patrick. Query performance is much more important that query length. All the alternate solutions mentioned have a slower performance than your original one.